# Prevent window from being dragged between spaces

Tags: cocoa, window, drag, spaces

There is a feature in Lion MacOS allowing a window **to be dragged into other spaces**. I would like to **disable** this opportunity for my NSWindow.

I have basic window with collectionBehavior set up to join all spaces. And I am implementing the ability to drag a sub-view into separate window (floating). When user drags this floating window to the edge of the screen, Lion switches spaces automatically. And that is not a desired behavior.

How can I disable this window dragging between spaces?

Comment: Any ideas would be good! Or am I asking something that nobody ever wanted to implement? :)

Comment: Well, I don't know how, but as a side note, as a user, I am always frustrated when I cannot get a window to change spaces :)

Comment: Well, when you have the window present in all spaces, there is no need to drag it from one to another. That is why I want to disable this function. Besides there are some drawing bugs after space is changed...